# column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-10

I have a simple table with columns col1, col2, col3. All not nullable.

I want to delete all rows where the tuple (col1, col2) has several entries. Background: a unique constraint for (col1, col2) should be added.

```
drop table mytable;

create table mytable (
    col1 integer not null,
    col2 integer not null,
    col3 integer not null);

-- rows to delete
insert into mytable values (1, 1, 1);
insert into mytable values (1, 1, 2);

-- rows to keep
insert into mytable values (2, 2, 1);
insert into mytable values (2, 3, 2);



delete from mytable where 
(col1, col2) in  (
    select col1, col2 from mytable  
    group by (col1, col2) having  count(distinct col3) >1) ;

select * from mytable;
```

Above works on PostgreSQL 10 but fails on older versions.

Older versions tell me this error message:

> ERROR:  column "mytable.col1" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

How to get this working on PG 9.3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to remove the parentheses around the columns in `group by (col1, col2)`. This works in version 9.4 and previous as well:

```
delete from mytable  
where (col1, col2) in  (
    select col1, col2 from mytable  
    group by col1, col2                   -- <-- changed
    having  count(distinct col3) >1) ;
```

The reason that it fails (I think) is that while `(col1, col2)` is equivalent to `row(col1, col2)`, there was some inconsistency in how it was handled in the various clauses which was fixed in 9.5. In previous versions, you could use a more complex construction in `WHERE`: `WHERE (SELECT (col1, col2)) IN ...`. So this should work in 9.3 as well:

```
delete from mytable
where (select (col1, col2)) in  (
    select (col1, col2) from mytable  
    group by (col1, col2) having  count(distinct col3) >1) ;
```

Comment: O what fun. I am laughing about myself. Thank you very much! I tried to find the solution in the select-part. I never looking at the characters behind the "group by".

Comment: I'm not 100% confident about the explanation by the way. It might have to do with the addition of `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` and `CUBE` in 9.5 as that involved changes in `GROUP BY` handling.